# How to change keyboard view in android after pressing any key

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an Edittext field and want the user to be able to enter the text very quickly. The text that will be entered begins with a capital letter followed by a set of numbers only. So after entering the first letter I want the keyboard view to switch to show numbers only. Here is my code for the edittext listener:

```
final EditText carPlate=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.carPlateNumber);
carPlate.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(carPlateCharnum==0){
            carPlate.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
                            carPlateCharnum++;
            return true;
        }
        // if keydown and "enter" is pressed
        if ((event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                && (keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {

            // display a floating message

            DisplayToast(carPlate.getText().toString() + carPlateCharnum);
            carPlateCharnum++;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
});
```

The problem is the keyboard view is only switching after I press the enter key. So I need to know where and how to put this part of code:

```
if(carPlateCharnum==0){
        carPlate.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        carPlateCharnum++;
        return true;
    }
```

Also I don't want the insertion point to return to the beginning of the EditText field after entering the first letter.

Comment: You can't.  There's no api for the application to inform the keyboard that the type has changed.  Its possible that it would cause the InputMethodService to get a onStartInputView called, but not likely.  And if it did most keyboards would become at least slightly broken, if not majorly.  The assumption is that a field has 1 type that does not change while the user is typing.

Comment: Should i then do two editText field one for the letter and one for the number? But then is there a way after entering one letter in the first text field to automatically jump to the second?

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard has to reinitialize itself to be informed about the changes in the EditText carPlate.
(Detail-Info: `TextView.onCreateInputConnection()` returns the new `InputType` to the `InputMethodManager`).

```
carPlate.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
((InputMethodManager) YourActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
        .restartInput(carPlate);
```